# why jdk proxy could not be injected

Tags: spring

I use Aspect like this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class DataSourceAspect {
    @Pointcut("@target(com.chen.dynamicsource.aspect.DataSource)")
    public void pointCut() {

    }

    @Before("pointCut()")
    public void doBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {}
}
```

And I add it to application.yml:

```
spring
  aop:
    proxy-target-class: false
```

When I run the application. I get the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'dispatcherServlet' could not be injected because it is a JDK dynamic proxy

The bean is of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67' and implements:
    org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware
    org.springframework.core.env.EnvironmentCapable
    org.springframework.context.EnvironmentAware
    javax.servlet.Servlet
    javax.servlet.ServletConfig
    java.io.Serializable
    org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy
    org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised
    org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy

Expected a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet' which implements:
```

I know I can use statically evaluated pointcut designators like within () and change the value of proxy-target-class to true to avoid the problem.
But I just want to know why jdk proxy could not be injected.

Comment: Because a JDK proxy is interface based and not classbased. So when a proxy is created it creates a dynamic class implementing all interfaces of the adviced class. So now things that require the actual class will fail as that isn't that class anymore but rather a dynamic class implementing the interfaces. A class proxy will extend the class to proxy to add the behavior leaving it a class of that type. Using class proxies is actually the default in Spring Boot so you actually disabled it.

Comment: Clearly. So if I use a JDK proxy to proxy a class that implements an A interface, then I inject the proxy class into the interface, and it will work fine.

Comment: If your class has an interface you should always inject/program with that interface and not the concrete class. The interface is a contract and you want something that implements the contract (else don't use an interface).